# QRCode scanner in Uno Platform

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, uno-platform

I'm looking for alternatives to scan a QRCode in Uno.

Is it possible to use ZXing or other lib to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, if it's a Xamarin Forms project, you could install [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) to use. I'm not sure whether the uno plaform could use as the same.

Comment: Yes it would be the same approach or uno.

Comment: I got it working! I will post the solution here later. Is necessary to use the ZXing.Net.Mobile basic classes. Tks Guys

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible to use XZing ! I've done it in the past.

I've used the ZXing.Net.Mobile package from Redth [github link](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile)

Create a custom control. Like so

```
public partial class BarcodeScanner : Control
```

Create a Style for it and set DefaultStyleKey properly

When the control loads (OnLoaded), in C# create the surfaceviews and things you need to do with ZXing. I think I had to do a little bit of #if __ ANDROID __ and #if __ IOS __ for some details.

Comment: can you share how you've done that? I'm struggled here :/ Tkss

Comment: @MuriloMacielCurti I don't have code I can share quickly. But I'll edit my answer to give more details high-level.